# Fit 4 variable proportion images into multi image carousel (Bootstrap 5 responsive)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I found this Bootstrap 5 carousel which almost does what I need:
https://codepen.io/hellomev/pen/LYORMQW

HTML

```
<div class="container text-center my-3">
    <div class="row mx-auto my-auto justify-content-center">
        <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-img">
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700x500.png/CB997E/333333?text=1" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 1</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-img">
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700x500.png/DDBEA9/333333?text=2" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 2</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-img">
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700x500.png/FFE8D6/333333?text=3" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 3</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-img">
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700x500.png/B7B7A4/333333?text=4" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 4</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-img">
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700x500.png/A5A58D/333333?text=5" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 5</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-img">
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700x500.png/6B705C/eeeeee?text=6" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 6</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev bg-transparent w-aut" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next bg-transparent w-aut" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

CSS

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item > div {
        display: none;
    }
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item > div:first-child {
        display: block;
    }
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
    display: flex;
}

/* medium and up screens */
@media (min-width: 768px) {

    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-end.active,
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
        transform: translateX(25%);
    }

    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-start.active, 
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
        transform: translateX(-25%);
    }
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-end,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-start { 
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

JS

```
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel .carousel-item')

    items.forEach((el) => {
        const minPerSlide = 4
        let next = el.nextElementSibling
        for (var i=1; i<minPerSlide; i++) {
            if (!next) {
        // wrap carousel by using first child
        next = items[0]
    }
    let cloneChild = next.cloneNode(true)
    el.appendChild(cloneChild.children[0])
    next = next.nextElementSibling
    }
})
```

I'm working with variable sized and proportioned images.

I have a local version with varying sized / proportioned images. In that portrait images stick out of the bottom of the carousel (which I assume is designed for fixed sized images, probably 16:9).

I need a solution that will make all images fit and look right.

This could be centring and hiding overflow, or it could be resizing to show the full image if it's portrait (so it'd be less wide), however this might break the carousel as 4 images wouldn't fit neatly across the width then.

I've tried updating a lot of the CSS/HTML, adding many styles to .card-img, but there's way too much going on and what I did (adjusting max-height at responsive widths) seemed very hacky and didn't work.

How can I centre and trim overvlow, resize within a max width and max height (without breaking the width of the carousel), or do something else to make the photos fit?